# Android: Back to App after setting wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

In myActivity, This is my code to check if my phone connect to the Internet or not.

```
if (!isConnected()) {
            // super.playingVideo.setVideoUrl(product.getVideoUrl());
            String message = getResources().getString(R.string.wifi_prompt);
            super.showDialog(this, message, R.string.wifi_setting,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            if (dialog != null) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            currentProduct = product;
                            isViewRequest = true;
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

                        }
                    }, R.string.back, dismissDialogListener);
        } else {...}
```

And to the resume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // After setting wifi
    if (isViewRequest) {
        ...//mycode
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

My problem is, when I've done setting wifi connection and press back button. It back to the menu screen of my phone, not resume myActivity.
Only if I launch my app again after that, the onResume() function is executed.
So, what's my missing to back to my app after setting wifi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is your answer I think , you have to open the settings as ActivityForResult :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
```

You can implement it in an `AlertDialog` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to go to wifi settings?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // Activity transfer to wifi settings
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                    }
                });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("no",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: My problem is not about the dialog. It's about how to back to my app after setting wifi. I my code above, I back to the phone's menu, not my app.

Comment: This should be enough , I updated my answer as well :

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);`

Comment: Using startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0); work for me now. Thanks for your help.