# startActivityForResult - WIFI Settings Don't Go Back To App

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, android-wifi

I'm starting an intent to `Settings - Wireless`, the problem was whenever I press `KeyBack`. It will not go back to my App, instead It closes it.

```
wifiManagerCheck = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (!checkWifiEnabledSwitch(wifiManagerCheck)){
        //NOTIFY THROUGH SNACK BAR ACTION TO SETTINGS
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"No internet",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Turn on", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);
            }
        }).show();
    }
```

Is this correct? I base this one in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882479/android-back-to-app-after-setting-wifi):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in the  for the activity, is there something like noHistory=true?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot this one, I set in my `Manifest` - `noHistory = true`.